# Inserted nodes in red-black tree get wrong colouring

Tags: java, red-black-tree

I want to change the color of root Node to black when the color of root.right and root are red.
Now In this code first i insert 5 so color of this root will be black.Then i inserted 6 then color of this node will be red then i inserted 7 then color of this node will be red.So now This node and the previous node have red color So here i need to change the color of previous Node which contains data=6

```
package redblack;

public class Redblack {
public enum Color {
   red,black,blue
};
   static class Node{
      int data;
      Color color;
      Node right;
      Node parent;
      Node(int data){
          color=Color.black;
          this.data=data;
          right=null;
          parent =null;
      }
  }  
        static Node insertion(Node root,int data){
      if(root==null){
          Node root1=new Node(data);
          return root1;
      }
      if(root.data<data){
      root.right=insertion(root.right,data);
      root.right.parent=root;
      root.right.color=Color.red;
      if(root.parent!=null)
      root.color=Color.black; // Whats wrong here?
      }
      return root;
  }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
  Node root=new Node(5);
  root=insertion(root,6);
  root=insertion(root,7);
    System.out.println(root.right.color); //Getting red color but i want black color here
 }

}
```

Comment: something like this https://prnt.sc/gxap80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the color to red here:

```
root.right.color=Color.red;
```

So this line has to print red instead of black:

```
System.out.println(root.right.color);
```

Note that even if you set the color of `root.right` to red inside of the inner call to `insertion`, when it returns to the outter `insertion` you do this:

```
root.right=insertion(root.right,data);
...
root.right.color=Color.red;
```

so, you are overwriting whatever color you had set `root.right` to be always red.

Comment: No that is the color of the root I want color of root.right to be black.something like this https://prnt.sc/gxap80

Comment: Updated the answer with further explanation

Answer (score 0):

you are not assigning any value to the root.parent so it will always be null you and in this code `root=insertion(root,7);` you are deleting the previous right and re inserting new one with the color red you should replace this `root=insertion(root,7);` with `root.right=insertion(root.right,7);`